# Replacing all text in powerpoint using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

I looked at the apache POI documentation and created a function that redacts all the text in a powerpoint. Function works well in replacing texts in slides but not the texts found in grouped textboxes. Is there seperate object that handles the grouped items?

```
private static void redactText(XMLSlideShow ppt) {
    for (XSLFSlide slide : ppt.getSlides()) {
        System.out.println("REDACT Slide: " + slide.getTitle());

        XSLFTextShape[] shapes = slide.getPlaceholders();

        for (XSLFTextShape textShape : shapes) {

            List<XSLFTextParagraph> textparagraphs = textShape.getTextParagraphs();

            for (XSLFTextParagraph para : textparagraphs) {

                List<XSLFTextRun> textruns = para.getTextRuns();

                for (XSLFTextRun incomingTextRun : textruns) {

                    String text = incomingTextRun.getRawText();

                    System.out.println(text);

                    if (text.toLowerCase().contains("test")) {

                        String newText = text.replaceAll("(?i)" + "test", "XXXXXXXX");

                        incomingTextRun.setText(newText);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the need is simply getting all text contents independent of in what objects it is, then one could simply do exactly that. Text contents are contained in `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString` elements. In `PowerPoint` `XML` they are in `a:t` tags. Name space a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main".

So following code gets all text in all objects in all slides and does replacing case-insensitive string "test" with "XXXXXXXX".

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTSlide;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlString;

public class ReadPPTXAllText {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("MicrosoftPowerPoint.pptx"));
  for (XSLFSlide slide : slideShow.getSlides()) {
   CTSlide ctSlide = slide.getXmlObject();
   XmlObject[] allText = ctSlide.selectPath(
    "declare namespace a='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main' " +
    ".//a:t"
   );
   for (int i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
    if (allText[i] instanceof XmlString) {
     XmlString xmlString = (XmlString)allText[i];
     String text = xmlString.getStringValue();
System.out.println(text);
     if (text.toLowerCase().contains("test")) {
      String newText = text.replaceAll("(?i)" + "test", "XXXXXXXX");
      xmlString.setStringValue(newText);
     }
    }
   }
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("MicrosoftPowerPointChanged.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  slideShow.close();
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If one doesn't like the approach of replacing via Xml directly, it is possible to iterate over all slides and their shapes. If a shape is a `XSLFTextShape`, get the paragraphs and handle them like you did. 
If you receive a `XSLFGroupShape`, iterate over their `getShapes()` as well. Since they could contain different types of shapes you might use recursion for that. You might handle the shape type `XSLFTable` also.

But the real trouble starts when you realize, that something you want to replace is divided into several runs ;-)